# Power Apps portal integration with Dynamics 365 On premise

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-365, power-automate

I have a question about the integration between dynamics 365 and PowerPlatform.

There is a way to connect Dynamics 365 on premise with :
PowerApps portal
PowerApps Canevas
Power Automate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data gateway to connect cloud power apps with your on-premise data. Please find the below links for official Microsoft documentation on the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/gateway-reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/gateway-manage

Hope this helps to give you a little insight on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you four the response, the gateway will allow me just to connect to dynamics 365 onpremise database (sql server) for read operations. But we cannot use it to connect PowerApps portal to my CRM.

Comment: Same thing for PowerApps Canevas and Powerapps, we cannot use CDS or Dynamics 365 connectors, it is limited to sql server connectors

Comment: What is you are actually trying to achieve if you can elaborate a little. It might help.

Comment: If you are looking for a possible to update the data back to the On premise and if it a simple insert/update operation, you can go through the link here : https://www.briteglobal.com/blogs/community/integrate-cds-sql-onprem-data-gateway/
You can also look into deploying an On Premise portal as well